# Prove that $N_n\smallsetminus\{a\}\leftrightarrows N_{n-1}$ ($\leftrightarrows$ means bijection)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

To prove this I constructed a function $f(N) = N\setminus\{a\}$ such that

$$f(N) = \{1,2,3,....a-1,a+1,...n\}$$

and

$$f(n) = \{x:1 \leq x\leq n-1\land x\in N_n\setminus\{a\}\}$$

How do I go about proving this via bijectivity.
For injectivity I tried constructed a set such that $y,z$ elements of $f(N)$, and equated $f(y) = f(z)$ to prove it is injective via contradiction.
I stated that $f(y) =  x_1$ which is an element of $N\setminus\{a\}$
and that f(z) where $z = n$
has $f(n) = a$.
since $a$ is not equal to $x_1$, I concluded that the function is injective.
Is this enough.

The surjective part is easy I know how to define that, i just created a function $f(x)$ such that:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{for }x\neq a \\ a & \text{for }x=a\end{cases}.$$

Is my argument for injectivity sound?

Comment: I take it $N_n$ are the natural numbers from 1 to $n$, i.e. $N_n=\{m\in\mathbb N:1\leq m\leq n\}$. Maybe you meant to prove $|N_n\smallsetminus\{a\}|=n-1$, i.e. taking away any element $a$ from $N_n$ you get a set of cardinality $n-1$? $$\,$$ Also, what was that `f)\_` supposed to mean?

Comment: that last part was a mistake, i fixed it.

Comment: «that last part was a mistake, i fixed it» but I still see `f)_` right there…
$$\,$$
What _was_ the question? Bijection between $N_n\smallsetminus\{a\}$ and $N_n\smallsetminus\{1\}$? Bijection between $N_n\smallsetminus\{a\}$ and $N_{n-1}$?

Comment: The latter. If it is bijective it should coincide with Nn-1,

Comment: So $f$ should be a function from $N_n\smallsetminus\{a\}$ to $N_{n-1}$. I would simply say:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & x<a \\ x-1 & x>a \end{cases}.$$
Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x,y\in N_n\smallsetminus\{a\}$. We have three cases: either $x,y<a$, but on that set $f$ is the identity, so $x=y$; or $x<a,y>a$ (which is the same as its viceversa $x>a,y<a$), but then $f(x)=x<a\leq y-1=f(y)$, so $f(x)\neq f(y)$; or $x>a,y>a$, but then $f$ acts like the identity minus a constant, so $x=y$.

Comment: It is also surjective, since if $x\in N_{n-1}$, either $x<a$, and then $x=f(x)$, or $x\geq a$, and then $x=f(x+1)$.
$$\,$$
You seem to be considering a set-valued function $f$. Why would you do that?