# meaning of $\leftrightarrows$

Tags: category-theory, notation

What is the meaning of $\leftrightarrows\,$?

It has been suggested that it is a synonym for $\leftrightarrow$ or $\Leftrightarrow$ or both, but in MSE posts it appears to have some other meaning associated with category theory.

Comment: In what context did you find the symbol exactly? Or are we to look for instances of it on MSE ourselves? We're all volunteers, you know?

Comment: I've never seen it used before. I would assume it's a synonym for $\Leftrightarrow$ given no other context; in category theory I can imagine someone using it as a symbol for an adjunction. Can you link to where you saw it?

Comment: @shaun thank you for telling me you are a volunteer, so am I.  The 2204 answers I have provided on MSE have all been given voluntarily.  That's why I searched for the symbol on MSE while writing my question.  I found nothing except some unexplained uses which were mostly tagged "category theory".  If you feel you can do a better search than I did, then your voluntary assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan it was asked me by a student.  It was a general question about logical symbols such as $\to$, $\Rightarrow$ and so on.  So apologies, but no context.

Comment: I'm not aware of an extremely well-established meaning for this symbol.

Comment: The only use of the symbol I found in [this Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cleftrightarrows%24&p=8) was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2280645/104041), in which it is a bijection.

Comment: Thanks for that @shaun, didn't know about Approacho.  Much appreciated.  Will wait and see if anyone out there has actually used this symbol in "real life" :)

Comment: If you were drawing a category in a hasty way in LaTeX, I guess you could use overseas and undersets to represent morphisms going in each direction between two objects.

Comment: I mean I'd use this symbol for an adjunction, and I've seen it used that way all over the place, like $L:\mathcal{C}\leftrightarrows \mathcal{D}:R$. Although, I should say, it doesn't itself mean adjunction, just that $L$ goes right, $R$ goes left.

Comment: I use it often for split epimorphisms, which is a special case of what Mark S suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question in order to summarise people's useful comments.  Thanks everyone!

- The symbol can be used to indicate a bijection, as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280645).
- In category theory: morphisms going both ways/adjunction/split epimorphisms.